# Two tabulars in one Table but in different pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking

[image]I would like to ask you how could I have in one table two parts (tabulars) BUT in different pages?
I tried bigskip or pagebreak but it does't work

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Especially a screen shot or a sketch would help

Comment: Have you considered to use a `longtable` and placing the two `tabular` environments inside? Should the two parts be side-by-side or stacked?

Comment: Thank you very much Christian. I appreciate your help. I am newy in LATEX tables. I want the two parts(panels) of the table to be stacked but in different pages. For example in page 1 would be {{Panel A...} and in page 2 would be {Panel B...} of the SAME Table. I used longtable but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the filler on the second page, above Panel B?

Comment: You don't have to use longtable. If yu have your tabulars, put them in minipages each and set a caption with `\captionof{table}{Your caption}`. But i hvae a little trouble imagining the desired output. An MWE (as already requested by @ChristianHupfer Hupfer) might help.

Comment: @Johannes_B: The proposition with `longtable` was before the *precise* configuration was known.

Comment: Do you mean you have two actually different table, but  you want only one caption for the whole set (sort of ‘logical table’)?

Comment: @ThanosSak: Those two tables in your screenshot are not stacked really, they are side-by-side, on verso-recto pages however

Comment: Christian they are at different pages. Sorry,yes you are right they are not stacked. What you mean by side-by-side?

Comment: @ThanosSak: Both panels seem to be of equal size, having the same distance to the topmargin of their pages, so I would say, they are side-by-side, however, on two pages

Comment: Yes. Exactly Christian.

Comment: @ThanosSak: In your comment about 1 hour ago you wrote that they are `stacked` ;-)

Comment: @Christian. Yes, you are right. Sorry for that. What I want is to have two Panels (I do not care if they have the same size) in two pages that belong in one table.Thank you again.

Comment: @ThanosSak: I updated my solution -- they are in one table, spanning two pages, the `\savebox` is not really necessary, but I kept it.

Answer (score 2):

A proposition: Store one tabular (PanelA) in a savebox, call it inside a `longtable` environment and then introduce a `\newpage` for the next page, use a `\phantom{\usebox{....}}` (see code) and then continue with the second panel tabular.

As long as there is no precise information, what fills the place on the second page, I took the spacing produced by `PanelA`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{longtable}%

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\PanelABox}

\savebox{\PanelABox}{\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{Panel A} \tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{longtable}{c}%
\hline
\tabularnewline
\usebox{\PanelABox} \tabularnewline
\hline
\newpage
\hline
\tabularnewline
\phantom{\usebox{\PanelABox}} \tabularnewline
\hline
\begin{tabular}{l}
\textbf{Panel B}
\end{tabular}%

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** After update of the OP's precise request

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{longtable}%



\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\PanelABox}

\savebox{\PanelABox}{\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Panel A} \tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}%



\begin{longtable}{|c|}%
\hline
\tabularnewline
\usebox{\PanelABox} \tabularnewline
\hline
\newpage
\hline
\tabularnewline
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Panel B} \tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular} \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why so complicated?

Comment: @thanos Do you care if the tables are visible on the same *open page couple* (panel A left and panel B right)?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I considered your *objection* also, I believe, that both panels should be on the verso-recto combination, not vice versa, but I do not have added some code to guarantee this ...